# Show half portion of image side by side on two separate glcontrols - openTK

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, opentk

I have a single texture and two glControls.  I need to show the  first half portion of texture on glControl2 and second half portion of texture on glControl1. 
And also I have put two numericupdown controls on left end of texture (range from 0 to 0.5) and another two numericupdown controls on right end of texture (range from 0.5 to 1.0). When I select 0. 4 and 0. 5 on left end of texture,  I have to show the area between 0. 4 and 0. 5 on glControl2. 
And If I select 0. 8 and 1 on right end of texture,  I have to show the area between 0. 8 and 1. 0 on glControl1. I have tried like by referring this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53429788/show-half-portion-of-image-side-by-side-opengl/53431171?noredirect=1#comment93823133_53431171) .  But not getting correctly.

```
       public void CreateShaders()
    {
        /***********Vert Shader********************/
        vertShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.VertexShader);
        GL.ShaderSource(vertShader, @"attribute vec3 a_position;
                                    varying vec2 vTexCoordIn; 

                                    void main() {
                           vTexCoordIn=( a_position.xy+1)/2 ;                                 
                           gl_Position = vec4(a_position,1);

     }");
        GL.CompileShader(vertShader);

        /***********Frag Shader ****************/
        fragShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.FragmentShader);
        GL.ShaderSource(fragShader, @"precision highp float;

    uniform sampler2D sTexture_2;
    uniform float sSelectedRangeLeft;   
    uniform float sSelectedRangeRight;
    uniform float sSelectedRangeLeftEnd;   
    uniform float sSelectedRangeRightEnd;
    uniform int sCurrentGLControl;
    varying vec2 vTexCoordIn;
    void main ()
    {

vec2 vTexCoord=vec2(vTexCoordIn.x,vTexCoordIn.y);

float rightsliderStartval=sSelectedRangeRight;//0.5 to 1.0
float rightsliderEndval=sSelectedRangeRightEnd;//1.0 to 0.5
float rightsliderDelta=rightsliderEndval-rightsliderStartval;

float leftsliderStartval=sSelectedRangeLeftEnd;//0.0 to 0.5
float leftsliderEndval=sSelectedRangeLeft;//0.5 to 0.0
float leftsliderDelta=leftsliderEndval-leftsliderStartval;

 if(sCurrentGLControl==1)//GLControl1
 {
 vec4 colorLeft= texture2D(sTexture_2, vec2((0.5+vTexCoord.x)-(0.5-rightsliderStartval)-(1.0-rightsliderEndval), vTexCoord.y));
 gl_FragColor = colorLeft;

}
 else if(sCurrentGLControl==2) //GLControl2
 {  
 vec4 colorRight= texture2D(sTexture_2, vec2(((vTexCoord.x-0.75)*2.0) +(leftsliderStartval), vTexCoord.y));
 gl_FragColor = colorRight;  
 }
 }");
        GL.CompileShader(fragShader);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a conditional logic in the shader it seams much simpler to create 2 controls and re-position the geometry (or change a view-port / camera) according to the constrains.

[image]

**Update**
I propose following approach to accomplish your task:

- Create 2 rectangles representing a full view area each
- In Paint handler **of each** glControl

  - Position/scale rectangle or adjust a view port (camera) **according to values** in **relevant** updown controls
  - Apply shader
  - Draw rectangle

Comment: Not only wants to show half portion of texture exactly. But also i want to select particular area from texture as explained in the question.

Comment: Updated the answer - tell me if it makes sense now.

Comment: Viewport values only accept integer values.  Updown controls have values range from 0. 0 to 1. 0

Comment: By viewport I considered one of the View | Model |
Projection matrices... Not sure what Viewport property do you mention but if it's integer to can divide it by width/height in order to normalize